# Cant import Double

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Double {



public static void main(String[] args) {
        
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        
double n1, n2, sum;
System.out.println("Enter the first number:");
n1 = in.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter the second number:");
n2 = in.nextDouble();
in.close();
sum = n1 + n2;
System.out.println("the sum is " + sum);

}

}
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException 
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
at Double.main(Double.java:12)
```

its giving me this problem when im right the number 5.6 and if i right number 5 its ok
ia the problem is on eclipse ide or somthing about my code

Comment: Don't write a class called `Double`. That's the name of [a class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) that's part of the language.

Comment: Your code is correct. Just change the name of your class to something else as already suggested by khelwood and it will work.

Comment: @khelwood There is no problem because the package names are different.

Comment: @saka1029 It's still a bad idea, even if the code works.

Comment: i changed the class name its still dosent working

Comment: @ Arvind Kumar Avinash

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK and you don't need to change class name. Your problem is in your input. You are trying to read input from `system in` but I think you forget to add inputs as parameters.

See your working code [here!](http://tpcg.io/dHX1rAzh). (Just add 1 2 3 in the STDIN section)

Or just run your code in shell to work in interactive mode.

Comment: In eclipse you must enter your inputs in *run->run configuration* or just compile and run your code in the shell.